# What Records did Yoav Bruck break as a swimmer?

Tags: olympics, swimming, records

I know Yoav Bruck broke a few records during his time at the swimming pool. Can you tell me what they are? Does he still hold any that haven't been broken yet?

Comment: Welcome. This question asks for a rather large list. Generally we close questions that ask for a big list of things.

Answer (score 1):

These are Yoav Bruck's records:

- Yoav Bruck was the first Israeli swimmer that made it to the finals
  in the world championship and the Olympics.
- Bruck held the Israeli records in the prestigious **100 meter freestyle** event and 50 meter
  freestyle event for 19 years and the Israeli record in **200 meter
  freestyle** for 12 years.
- Yoav Bruck still holds the Israeli records in
  **100 meter** and **50 meter freestyle** in a 25 meter pool.